# Wireless controllers don't pick up input using the old input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, wireless

I need assistance with a Unity wireless controller issue that I'm encountering. Specifically, I am unable to get input from wireless controllers such as PS4, PS5, and Xbox controllers, while the same controller connected via cable does work. It's worth noting that I am using the old input system in Unity, not the new one. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

Although the wireless controllers do function correctly when I use the new input system, I'm not prepared to update my project and want to continue using the old input system. I'm hoping to get some suggestions on how to address this issue.

I am using **Unity 2021.3.8f1** and **2020.3.36f1**

I'm experiencing an issue with my Unity script where it works perfectly fine with wired controllers, but doesn't work with wireless controllers (I am using the old input system in Unity). I've tried using different wireless controllers such as PS4, PS5, and Xbox controllers, but none of them seem to work. I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to make it work with wireless controllers as well.

**Update:** I am using Unity's legacy input system to detect controller, keyboard, and mouse inputs. All are working fine except wireless controllers.

Here is the simple script, and even I am unable to detect `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")`:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WirelessController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 100f;

    void Update () {

        float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;

        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        rotation *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);
        transform.Rotate(0, rotation, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are at least 9 versions of [unity input system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/Migration.html).  Please be more specific about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @James I have made an update to my post and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. My controller worked perfectly when wired, but when I switched to wireless mode, Unity recognized it, but it didn't register any inputs.

Comment: What driver are you using for the wireless controller?  Always use vendor supplied driver and do not use Microsoft Generic Driver.  This sounds like a driver issue.

Comment: @jdweng I discovered that my wireless controller is actually functioning with the new input system without requiring any driver changes. So, it's unclear why it's not working with the legacy system

Comment: Are you sure the driver didn't change?

Comment: @jdweng I have a project with two different scripts, one using the new input system and the other using the legacy input system. The script with the new input system is working fine with the wireless controller

Comment: You may of overwritten the old driver and need the old driver with old project.

Comment: @jdweng I am confused, I literally don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: What type interface if the wireless controller?  Is it USB?  If you switch between new and old controller does the driver change (check with device manager)?  Are you using a  Vendor Driver or a Generic Microsoft Driver?  Using vendor drivers are usually the best choice.

Comment: I had the same issue. It seemed like a driver problem. However, after upgrading the project to 2022.2.13f, the wireless controller is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue where wired controllers were working fine, but wireless controllers didn't work. It seemed like a driver problem as suggested by @jdweng

However, upgrading the project to version 2022.2.13f fixed the issue for me. I recommend updating your Unity to a version 2022.2.13f or higher, as it continues to support PS5 development and also seems to have fixed the wireless functionality.